# How to retrieve object's contents from a node within a Linked List in java

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, nodes, singly-linked-list

I created a Person Object that takes a string and an integer. I created a Node class to take in type generic as input. When I debug, I can see the objects are created, and stored, but my output is just memory addresses of said so objects. I tried parsing my objects to strings in my `toString()` method, but no luck. I have a hunch that the issue is the way I am declaring the generic datatype.
 Here is my code:

**Class Person**

```
public class Person {
   //variables
   private String name;
   private int age;

   // default const.
   public Person() {
      name = " ";
      age = 0;
   }
   // overloaded constructor
   public Person(String name, int age) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
   }
   // methods
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public void setAge(int age) {
      this.age = age;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public int getAge() {
      return age;
   }
}
```

**Class Node**

```
package LinkedList;


public class Node <T> {
   // added parameters for person object
   T p;

   Node nextNode;

   public Node () {

   }
   public Node (T p) {
      this.p = p;

   }

   // parse int data into string to simplify the unit test by not showing node memory locations
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return p.toString();
   }
}
```

**Linked List class**

```
package LinkedList;

public class myLinkedList <T>{
   //Nodes
   Node head;
   Node tail;
   int size = 0;

   // Generic method
   public void add (T p){
      Node node = new Node(p);
      if(tail == null){
         head = node;        // if no previous tail the new node is the head
         tail = node;        // if no previous tail the new node is also the tail
      }else {
         tail.nextNode = node;  // adds a node to the end of the list
         tail = node;           // the newest node is set to the tail;
      }
      size ++;
   }

   // Generic search method
   public Node search (T p) {
      //empty list
      if (head == null)
         return null;

      // check if the first node is a match
      if (head.p == p)
         return head;

      // assign node as iterator
      Node node = head;

      // iterate through linked list
      while (node.nextNode != null) {
         // assign the next node as current node
         node = node.nextNode;
         // compare current node's data to data
         if (node.p == p)
            System.out.println(" object found");
         return node;
         //exit when the last node is reached

      }
      return null;
   }

   public Node findPreviousNode (T p) {
      // if the current node has no previous node (it's the head)
      if(head.p == p)
      return new Node();

      Node node = head;
      //go through list looking for desired node and return the one before it
      while(node.nextNode != null) {

         if(node.nextNode.p == p)
         return node;
         // if desired node is not found move onto next node
         node = node.nextNode;

      }
      // returns null for previous node if desired node doesn't exist
      return null;
   }

   public Node delete (T p){

      // node selected to delete, initializes as null for a placeholder
      Node nodeToReturn = null;

      //empty list nothing to return
      if(size == 0)
      return null;

      //list of only one node
      if(size == 1) {
         nodeToReturn = head;
         head = null;
         tail = null;
         size --;
         return nodeToReturn;
      }

      // find and delete last node
      Node nodePrev = findPreviousNode(p);

      if(nodePrev.p == null) {

         head = head.nextNode;
         size --;

      } else if(nodePrev != null) {
         if(tail.p == p) {
            nodePrev.nextNode = null;
            tail = nodePrev;
         } else {

            nodePrev.nextNode = nodePrev.nextNode.nextNode;
         }
         size --;
      }

      return null;

   }

   public void traverse() {
      // checks for empty list and prints out the first node
      if(head != null) {
         Node node = head;
         System.out.print(node);

         // moves from node to node printing until it reaches null as nextNode
         while(node.nextNode != null) {

            node = node.nextNode;
            System.out.print( "  " + node.toString());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import LinkedList.*;

public class main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // implement linked list
      System.out.println("\n\n Object Linked list");
      myLinkedList peopleGroup = new myLinkedList();
      peopleGroup.add(new Person("robert", 23));
      System.out.println(peopleGroup.search("robert"));
      peopleGroup.add(mike);
      peopleGroup.add(marie);

      peopleGroup.traverse();
   }
}
```

**Output:** 
(I am guessing, same reason the search function is returning null is the culprit).

```
Object Linked list
null
Person@677327b6  Person@14ae5a5  Person@7f31245a
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you get are not memory addresses but hashes.

The default implementation of `toString()` is `ClassName@hashValue`.

Now you are overriding `toString()` in class `Node` to return the value of `Person.toString()` which is still the default implementation.

So if you now override `toString()` in class `Person` you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more meaningful strings you need to override toString in your Person class.

Comment: Ok, so add a toString() to the person class instead of having it in the Node class? Or in addition to (having it in both classes).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have few issues:

For match you should not dependent of `toString` method.

In the `search` method you are passing input as `String` (name). And to consider it a match you have conditions like if `(head.p == p)` and `if (node.p == p)`, where Node is a generic type(compile type), but technically it is `Person` object at runtime. So here you are comparing `String with Person Object`. Which is never going to give you a match at all.

If you want to match it, you need to override the `equals` method of `Person` Class as well as `hashcode`. As below:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
  if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    Person that = (Person) obj;
    if (this.age != that.getAge()) return false;
    if (!this.name.equals(that.getName())) return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17;

        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + age;
        return result;
    }
```

You can override these method according to your requirement and criteria of search. But along that you need to change code in `search` method as below :

```
// Generic search method
   public Node search (T p) {
      //empty list
      if (head == null)
         return null;

      // check if the first node is a match
      if (head.p.equals(p))
         return head;

      // assign node as iterator
      Node node = head;

      // iterate through linked list
      while (node.nextNode != null) {
         // assign the next node as current node
         node = node.nextNode;
         // compare current node's data to data
         if (node.p.equals(p))
            System.out.println(" object found");
         return node;
         //exit when the last node is reached

      }
      return null;
   }
```

And when you are passing Person from search, you need to pass the Person Object as below:

```
peopleGroup.search(new Person("robert", 23));
```

So after these changes you will get result, something like (Skipped adding mike and marie):

```
Object Linked list

test.file1.Person@518532a6

test.file1.Person@518532a6  test.file1.Person@6319ab2  test.file1.Person@bf8ccc2e
```

Comment: Thank you. After your comment I did notice I was passing a string instead of passing the name of an object to search. I changed my call of search to just pass in an object's name                                                                                                         ex. System.out.println(peopleGroup.search(robert));

Comment: So now, you will be getting correct result.